# How can I direct rsync output / log to the remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, rsync

I am able to output rsync logs on the client machine using `--log-file=FILE` but I want the output to be sent **to the server** instead. The client is a W7 machine (cygwin) and the server a Linux NAS.

This is the command I use which successfully logs the file on the client. I'm looking to have the file sent to the server instead:

```
rsync -PavOs --delete --log-file=/somepath/rsynclog.txt -e "ssh -i /somepath/keyfile -p 1000" "/somepath/User/" user@hostname.com:/somepath/User/
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have lost control of your question (as indicated by your edit) then please contact support via the help centre to get your accounts merged and so be able to mark an answer as correct: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 4):

From the [rsync manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> Here's a example command that requests the remote side to log what is
>   happening:

```
rsync -av --rsync-path="rsync --log-file=/tmp/rlog" src/ dest/
```

I think this is what you are searching for.